# Laravel - Carbon formatting time incorrectly

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I have two rows named `start_time` and `end_time` inside my database.
The start_time value is set as: `2018/07/11 12:00 am` and the `end_time` is set to: `2018/07/11 1:30 am`.

What I am trying to achieve is extracting the time only without displaying the date. I tried to use the following code

```
<table class="table-hover table">
    <tbody>
        @foreach($appointments as $appointment)
            <tr>
                <td>
                    {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($appointment->start_time)->format('h:m a')}} - 
                    {{Carbon\Carbon::parse($appointment->end_time)->format('h:m a')}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But it's displaying the time incorrectly. Instead of getting:

`12:00 am - 01:30 am` I keep on getting `12:07 am - 01:07 am`.

P.S: The date after parsing it becomes: `2018-07-11 00:00:00 - 2018-07-11 01:30:00`

Answer (score 2):

m - is a month

i - is a minute

[source](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)